# Counts instances for each category for many Matlab files

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matlab, scipy

This is for machine learning.  I have 5 matlab files: AWA, REM, S1, S2, SWS.
Each one has 2 arrays: `x` and `y`. `y` are the labels. I want to know the number of instances for each category in each file:

1. I load the matlab file
2. I convert from `f8` to `int32`
3. If I do not use `ravel`, `bincount` will not work
4. I count the instances for each category in the file

   I repeat these 4 steps 5 times (as there are 5 files). Is there a way to do it better?
5. Then I just join all the vectors in one array to send them to PANDAS.

```
#AWA
awa_y=sio.loadmat('/home/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
awa_y=awa_y.astype('int') #from f8 to int32 
awa=np.ravel(awa_y) #needed in order to use np.bincount()
AWA=np.bincount(awa)

#Rem
rem_y=sio.loadmat('/home/Rem_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
rem_y=rem_y.astype('int') 
rem=np.ravel(rem_y)
REM=np.bincount(rem)

#S1
s1_y=sio.loadmat('/home/S1_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
s1_y=s1_y.astype('int') 
s1=np.ravel(s1_y)
S1=np.bincount(s1)

#S2
s2_y=sio.loadmat('/home/S2_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
s2_y=s2_y.astype('int')
s2=np.ravel(s2_y)
S2=np.bincount(s2)

#SWS
sws_y=sio.loadmat('/home/SWS_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
sws_y=sws_y.astype('int')
sws=np.ravel(sws_y)
SWS=np.bincount(sws)

#Joining the 5 vectors 
table= (np.vstack((AWA, REM, S1, S2, SWS))).T 
TABLE = np.delete(table, (0), axis=0) 
print(TABLE)
```

Comment: `sio` appears to be [`scipy.io`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You felt it right, there's a lot of unnecessary copy/paste in the first part.

Your 5 data structures are similar, and you create a lot of variables to perform the same processing 5 times.

I did a quick factorisation which brings back the code to a reasonable 12 lines (I could not test, obviously, but that seems OK):

```
result_list = []

for name in ["AWA","Rem","S1","S2","SWS"]:
    xx_y=sio.loadmat('/home/{}_FeaturesAll.mat'.format(name))['y'].astype('int')
    xx=np.ravel(xx)
    result_list.append(np.bincount(xx))

#Joining the 5 vectors
table= (np.vstack(result_list)).T
TABLE = np.delete(table, (0), axis=0)
print(TABLE)
```

As the names are logical, I don't have to make a list of full names, only a part is enough. I just apply 5 times the same operation in the correct order, then store in `result_list`.

Joining the vectors is now a piece of cake. Just pass the result list.

Had you needed the individual vectors further in your code, then a `collections.OrderedDict` would be better to store them by name and recall them afterwards.